# Nhibernate and session pooling

Tags: c#, entity-framework, session, nhibernate

I'm working on a project where a new messeage should be insert into the table every 1 second. In EntityFramework, there is something called connection-pooling which makes it a better choice to keep the lifetime of the context as short as possible.We dispose the context. Does this apply to Nhibernate session?

```
ISessionFactory sf = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
ISession session = sf.OpenSession();
While(true)
{
//.......
    using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.SaveOrUpdate(msg);
        tran.Commit();                           
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Or

```
ISessionFactory sf = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
While(true)
{
//.......
    using(var session = sf.OpenSession())
    {
     using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
     {
         session.SaveOrUpdate(msg);
         tran.Commit();                           
     }
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Both seem to work, but which one shall I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can/should an NHibernate session be kept open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243835/how-long-can-should-an-nhibernate-session-be-kept-open)

Comment: It's worth taking a look at the `OpenStatelessSession` method on the `SessionFactory` interface. The stateless session concept seems a good fit for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well, if I decide to only answer your question:**

**second** code block is more appropriate. Actually, connection pooling has nothing to do with NHibernate. It is behavior of underlying RDBMS.

In NHibernate, creating `SessionFactory` is costly and should be done only once (at the startup ideally) in application lifetime. Creating `ISession` is not costly call. It is recommended that your session should be as short leaved as possible.

**More than just answer:**

Apart from short leaved session, you should also consider implementing `UnitOfWork` ("session-per-conversation" i.e. properly using transaction and session) to improve benefits of first level cache AND Batching.

First level cache is per session. If you run each DB call on new session, you are effectively not getting caching advantage.

Same is true for Batching. Batching is done based on how you handle your transactions. Call to `tran.Commit();` plays important role along with some other properties like `nhSession.FlushMode`, `nhSession.SetBatchSize`. Refer [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html) article.
To implement batching, I recommend you improve your **first** code block and instead of commiting the transaction in `using` block, you do it per 100 (or 10 or 500 whatever suits you) iterations of your loop.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41301400/5779732) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40817978/5779732) question.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243920/5779732) answer as said by @Fran in comments.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a lot. But in my case, the source data are aquired from a physical device,which generates one piece per second. So if I do batching like you said, the session needs to live for 500 seconds before it commits and disposed, which could violate the first rule.

Comment: Agree; batching does not help you in this case anyway.